# No devuelve valor consultado a Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, select

Tengo este codigo en php, se conecta con la sql, me imprime los datos necesarios cuando los encuentra en la misma, ahora cuando no lo encuentra lo unico que me marca es la palabra que escribe el usuario, lo que no puedo lograr hacer es que diga "no se encontró X en tu busqueda" si alguien me podria ayudar a solucionar esto, me vendria muy bien, ya que soy muy novato con php y sql

```
$tabla="";
$salida="";
$termino= "";
$consulta=" SELECT * FROM Productos LIMIT 0";


if(isset($_POST['Productos']))
{
    $termino=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Productos']);
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    codigo         LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    descripcion    LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    marca          LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    submarca       LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    oem            LIKE '%".$termino."%'";
}

$consultaBD=$mysqli->query($consulta);

if($consultaBD->num_rows>=1){
    $salida.="<table class='responsive-table table table-hover table-bordered'>
                   <thead>
                     <tr>
                     </tr>
                   </thead><br>
                   <tbody>";
    while($fila=$consultaBD->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $salida.= "<tr>
                   <td>".$fila['codigo']."</td> 
                   <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
                   </tr>";
    }
    $salida.= "</tbody>
               </table>";
}
else{
    $salida.= "no".$termino."no";
}

        echo $salida;
?>
```

con esto apenas tocar el input me sale "nono" al escribir una palabra que no esta en la base quedaria "no PALABRA no"
Lo que yo necesito es que hasta que el usiario no haga una busqueda que no este en SQl que no imprima nada en pantalla

[image: Muestra del problema sin escribir en el input]

Comment: `LIMIT 0` hará que no te traiga nada... por que haces limit 0 ?

Comment: Mm si me explicas mejor, como dije soy muy nuevo en esto y no sabría en que parte hacer el limit 0

Comment: Busca que hace el LIMIT y dime TU que haces usandolo ahi.

Comment: Bien, eso es para que cuando abras el cuadro de búsqueda no te salten los productos en la cara, si no toma la tabla y la imprime de primeras sin hacer ninguna busqueda

Comment: Fijate que $termino si lo tenes vacío simplemente al final te muestra vacío: echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>".$termino.  "</strong>"; Con respecto a LIMIT 0 es la cantidad máxima de resultados. Intenta colocar LIMIT 1

Comment: Entonces, si no hay POST, donde evaluas o desarrollas el que no encuentre nada ?

Comment: Es un buscador de productos dentro de la base de datos, pero si tu le pones LIMIT 1 o se lo quitas arroja los primeros datos de la sql ya que es en "tiempo real" la búsqueda, por ende al sacar el LIMIT o ponerle "1" trae el o los primer dato que encuentre en la base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente concatena a la variable el texto que quieres que se muestre cuando no hay coincidencias.

```
else{
    echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>No se encontró ".$termino." en tu búsqueda</strong>";
}
```

Y el resultado de la búsqueda sería algo similar a:

**No se encontró elValorBuscado en tu búsqueda**

**Edición:**

Para solucionar lo que comentas, puedes agregar una validación más en la que determinas si el `input` está vacío, no muestre nada en pantalla o muestre un mensaje de tipo **Ingresa un criterio de búsqueda**.

```
if(isset($_POST['Productos']) && $_POST['Productos'] != "")
{
    $termino=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Productos']);
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    codigo         LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    descripcion    LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    marca          LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    submarca       LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    oem            LIKE '%".$termino."%'";
}
else
{
   echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>Ingresa un criterio de búsqueda</strong>"; 
}
```

De hecho podrías ***y deberías*** incluir el query dentro de la validación. De este modo sólo se ejecutará cuando `$_POST['Productos']` esté seteado y no esté vacío.

```
if(isset($_POST['Productos']) && $_POST['Productos'] != "")
{
    $termino=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Productos']);
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    codigo         LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    descripcion    LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    marca          LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    submarca       LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    oem            LIKE '%".$termino."%'";

    $consultaBD=$mysqli->query($consulta);

    if($consultaBD->num_rows>=1){
        echo "
        <table class='responsive-table table table-hover table-bordered'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        </thead><br>
        <tbody>";
        while($fila=$consultaBD->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$fila['codigo']."</td>    
            <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>No se encontró ".$termino." en tu búsqueda</strong>";
    }
}
else
{
   echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>Ingresa un criterio de búsqueda</strong>"; 
}
```

Comment: De esa manera ya lo intente, pero de solo abrir el buscador te dice "No se encontró en tu búsqueda" sin que el usuario digite nada, en cuanto tocas el input salta el mensaje

Comment: edité mi respuesta para tratar de resolver esta segunda cuestión.

Comment: Acabo de re leer tu codigo, tome lo que me dijiste y simplemente medifique que no de valor alguno al no tener nada escrito en el input (Basicamente solo fue necesario borrar el ultimo echo "ingresa valor....), muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Me gustaría poder puntuarte, o recomendarte, no se como funciona esto, pero creo que se puede hacer algo de eso

Comment: Al lado izquierdo de las respuestas hay varias opciones. Puedes usar el check en esta respuesta para que quede marcada como aceptada y si gustas, también puedes hacer click en el botón hacia arriba para que ambos ganemos reputación.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo y si usas la funcion count para contar los resultados de tu consulta para así saber si tu consulta devolvió algo o no

(Respuesta editada)

```
<?php

$tabla="";
$consulta=" SELECT * FROM Productos LIMIT 0";
$termino= "";
if(isset($_POST['Productos']))
{
    $termino=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Productos']);
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    codigo         LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    descripcion    LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    marca          LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    submarca       LIKE '%".$termino."%' OR
    oem            LIKE '%".$termino."%'";

    $consultaBD=$mysqli->query($consulta);

    //Contar la cantidad de resultados
    $countResult = count($consultaBD);

    if($countResult > 0){
        echo "
        <table class='responsive-table table table-hover table-bordered'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        </thead><br>
        <tbody>";
        while($fila=$consultaBD->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$fila['codigo']."</td>    
            <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
    }else{
        
        echo "<strong class='busquedaN'>".'No se encontro '.$_POST['Productos']."</strong>";
        
    }
    
}
?>
```

Comment: Si, exacto eso es lo que quiero, pero ya lo e intentado y aun así no funciona, me tira error en cuanto abrís el buscador

Comment: Si nos muestras el error tal vez podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: busqueda.php on line 38
Call Stack

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, de pronto te sirva